# Use Moq to Verify if either method was called

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to write a test that verifies that either `Foo` or `FooAsync` were called.  I don't care which one, but I need to make sure at least one of those methods were called.

Is it possible to get `Verify` to do this?

So I have:

```
public interface IExample
{
    void Foo();
    Task FooAsync();
}

public class Thing
{
    public Thing(IExample example) 
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.Hours > 5)
           example.Foo();
        else
           example.FooAsync().Wait();
    }
}
```

If I try to write a test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Test
{
    [Test]
    public void VerifyFooOrFooAsyncCalled()
    {
        var mockExample = new Mock<IExample>();

        new Thing(mockExample.Object);

        //use mockExample to verify either Foo() or FooAsync() was called
        //is there a better way to do this then to catch the exception???

        try
        {
            mockExample.Verify(e => e.Foo());
        }
        catch
        {
            mockExample.Verify(e => e.FooAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I could try and catch the assertion exception, but that seems like a really odd work around.  Is there an extension method for moq that would do this for me?  Or is there anyway to get the method invocation count?

Comment: Under what circumstances does your code use the async version? I think you'd be better of checking the variables that lead to an async call and verifying that e.FooAsync is called under those circumstances and e.Foo otherwise.

Comment: @Kell - so my example is very simplistic to highlight the idea of two methods.  Checking the logic that leads to one method call vs the other isn't really feasible for me.  Part of this is, "I want my entire code base to by async", but not all of the code base is ready yet.  So I'd like my test to be robust, so that as my team slowly moves over to starting to use the async method, they don't have to worry about updating lots of tests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create setups for the methods and add callbacks for them, then use that to set a boolean to test.

e.g. something like:

```
var mockExample = new Mock<IExample>();

var hasBeenCalled = false;
mockExample.Setup(e => e.Foo()).Callback(() => hasBeenCalled = true);
mockExample.Setup(e => e.FooAsync()).Callback(() => hasBeenCalled = true);

new Thing(mockExample.Object);

Assert.IsTrue(hasBeenCalled);
```

Comment: Hmmm .. this is interesting.  How would it scale if say `Foo` changed to `Foo(int i)`.  And I wanted to verify either `Foo` or `FooAsync` was called with say value 5?

Comment: @PhilipPittle I don't see why that would be a problem. Just make the Setups more specific and then you will only get the callback happening under those conditions.

Comment: @OwenPauling - So there's no way to get the invocation count of a mock then?

Comment: @PhilipPittle you can increment a counter in the callback

Comment: But there's no way to interrogate a Mock directly?